# ANOVA with metric dependant variables?

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression

I often see multiple or simple linear regression coupled with ANOVA.
From my understanding, ANOVA is to test if there is a mean difference within a group, the values have then to be categorical or be like dummy variable 0-1 no? I fail to understand the ANOVA with metric dependant variable, and what if you have multiple dependant variables ?

Let`s say I have three metric variable:

- Response is user
- DV: time
- DV: temperature

The linear Regression Model would be:
**lm(user~time+temperature)**

The ANOVA Model would be the same
**aov(user~time+temperature)**

Answer (score 2):

An ANOVA is actually a kind of model comparison and the GLM framework is the one you should have in mind to understand the concept in all its generality, both for metric/continuous variables and for categoric variables (i.e. when you compare groups).

An ANOVA answers the question: if I add a given term to my model (time, temperature in your example, but also a categorical variable) does this term explains a significant portion of variance in the data? If yes ANOVA is significant.

When you do an ANOVA you compute an F value which is always something like:

$$
F = \frac{\textrm{explained variance}}{\textrm{unexplained variance}}
$$

For a categorical term I guess you have heard of the expression:

$$
F = \frac{\textrm{variance between groups}}{\textrm{variance within groups}}
$$

But in practice what you are computing (and this will be valid both for a categorical variable like group/treatment and a continuous variable like temperature) is a ratio of residual sums of squares $RSS(\textrm{X})$ where X indicates the set of variables in the model. For example computing an ANOVA for the term temperature (temp) in your model would look like this:

$$
F = \frac{\frac{RSS(\textrm{time})-RSS{(\textrm{time, temp}})}{2-1}}{\frac{RSS{(\textrm{time, temp}})}{n-2}}
$$

where $n$ is the number of observations.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Also how do you interpret the result of this formula if both of the variable are categorical (0-1) and give significant result? aov(user~Dummy 1+Dummy 2): Does that mean there is a mean difference in the group of  Dummy 1, and a mean difference for Dummy 2, does it take into account some sort of interaction of both of them?

Comment: if you want to include the interactions, then you need to add a term like Dummy1:Dummy 2 in your model. I guess you are using R, so you can try the command: anova(lm(user~Dummy1*Dummy 2)) which will tell you which of the following terms is significant:

1) Dummy1
2) Dummy2
3) Dummy1:Dummy2 (interaction term)

Comment: and if you do only aov(user~Dummy 1+Dummy 2). What does it tell exactly ?

Comment: try:
aov(mpg~vs+am,data=mtcars)
lm(mpg~vs+am,data=mtcars)
anova(lm(mpg~vs+am,data=mtcars))

you will see that:
1) aov output is a subset of the output of anova(lm(...)) (so the command aov appears unuseful and confusing to me)
 2) from anova(lm (...)) you see that both the effects of 'vs' and 'am' are significant, but if you run anova(lm(mpg~vs*am,data=mtcars)) you should see that the effect of the interaction is NOT significant.

Comment: now to the output of aov:
                      vs       am Residuals
Sum of Squares  496.5279 276.0333  353.4860
Deg. of Freedom        1        1        29

the Sum of squares line tells you the variance that has been explained by each term (496.52 for vs), while Residuals tell you the variance NOT explained by your model. in the model with the interaction (mpg~vs*am) variance is smaller, but not by "much", so the interaction is not significant.